# command line flume throws an error

Tags: logging, flume, cloudera

I want to collect logs from the console with flume, I start flume with the following command:

```
process_which_generates_the_log | flume node_nowatch -1 -n node -c 'node : console | agentBESink("localhost", 12345)'
```

but it says:

> 10/09/22 13:59:21 INFO agent.FlumeNode: Loading spec from command line: 'node : console | agentBESink("localhost", 12345)'
>
> 10/09/22 13:59:21 WARN agent.FlumeNode: Caught exception loading node:Parser error: unexpected 'null' at position -1 line 0: 'node : console | agentBESink("localhost", 12345)'

what am I missing? I followed [cloudera's howto](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/09/using-flume-to-collect-apache-2-web-server-logs/). it is expected to work isn't it?

Comment: Added in the tags that you wanted.

Comment: I won't get the badges for them but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've found it, a semicolon is needed!

the correct command is:

```
process_which_generates_the_log | flume node_nowatch -1 -n node -c 'node : console | agentBESink("localhost", 12345);'
```